# Sync Framework sync database view

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-sync-framework

can microsoft sync framework sync database views ?

or in your SelectIncrementalInsertsCommand can you select and join to multiple tables kinda doing something like a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sync Framework does not support Views. You can changes the SelectIncrementalInsertsCommand to return data, however you need to make sure it gives back exact schema expected, no extra columns no mis matched data types. There is another way if your scenario really demands extra info. You can manipualate the data set retrieved in the ChangesSelected event of Provider. However you need to be careful about performance hit here.

Answer (score 0):

Views are created dynamically on execution s you cant sync them.
BUT you can:

- aggregate the view's data into a table and then sync the table.
- Run the view on the synced tables on the target DB.